Does the addition of coloring ions change the IOR of glass?
The title is the question, but for a bit of context:
I'm exploring the viability of a various optical designs and one particular part of the design space becomes very interesting if the colored version of usable glasses have basically the same index of refraction as the uncolored version of the same type of glass (±0.0001 would be very interesting).
Despite searching and a bunch of different ways of asking, I haven't found anything explicitly saying one way or the other on if the IOR changes. However, several datasheets that list only one IOR but still mention multiple colors of glass (and the fact nobody seems to have any data on actual difference) tends to suggest that any difference may be minimal to the point of not being worth mentioning.
But I'd like something more definitive and can't justify setting up a glass making kit just to do the measurements myself.

Just wondering: what's a "coloring ion"?

@Transistor it turns out that one of the ways to make colored glass is to dope it with metals or their oxides. I haven't dug into it much, but I've seen them referred to as "ions" in that context. There are other ways of getting color, but they work at a much larger scale (e.g. such that you can't treat the glass as optically homogeneous) that don't work for my application and thus aren't of interest to me here.

Interpolation between oxides
One way to estimate the change in refractive index (RIX or $n$) versus color is to

Estimate the percentage impurity concentration to get some color, and
interpolate between the RIX's of the various oxides.

For example, let's say a Sapphire with some desired blue color contained 50ppm of Titanium (see this paper for some color examples in Sapphire).
Assuming the base material is Al2O3 (crystalline sapphire) with known RIX of 1.7682 (from refractiveindex.info).
Then take the RIX of TiO2 (I assume metal impurities are also oxides in the Al-O matrix), for example 2.6142 (also from refractiveindex.info).
Then linearly interpolate the RIX based on the concentration of TiO2, x, in the Al2O3 matrix like so:
$$Al_{2}O_{3}(λ) + x \cdot \left(TiO_{2}(λ) - Al_{2}O_{3}(λ)\right)$$
Where $Al_2O_3(λ)$ and $TiO_2(λ)$ are the RIX of each material at the wavelength λ.
In this case above (TiO2 impurity at $x$ = 50ppm within Al2O3 to produce blue sapphire), the RIX is estimated to increase by 0.0000423, at a wavelength of ~580nm (yellow light).
You will want to find better estimates of the impurity type and concentration for the colors and glass types you are looking into.  You may want to do the same analysis for $SiO_2$ (aka. fused silica) which is the most common type of glass optic, I just did Sapphire/Al2O3 because that's the first paper I found on color vs. impurity concentration.
Wavelength Dependence
Note you do need to choose a wavelength to find the RIX - and "colors" do mean absorption at certain wavelengths, so RIX may change more rapidly near the wavelength that is getting absorbed (for example, a yellow material color typically indicates that uv/blue light is being absorbed, so RIX near ~450nm might change a lot). This rapid change in RIX due to absorption will not be accounted for in a simple interpolation like the above.
(You may find this python module of various refractive indices and interpolation functions helpful: nk.py)

If that estimate is within even 10x of correct, that suggests that the arrangements I was considering are well worth considering.

Good! Please accept the answer if you think it solves your problem. You can always switch it if someone else submits a better answer. Thanks!

Out of curiosity, what is your application? (Could add to the original Q if so inclined)

Also - it depends how colored you want the glass. That’s where you’ll want to do a bit of internet sleuthing to find out what approx concentrations are needed to hit your desired color. The example I did above might be for very slight, dim color.

I omitted the arrangement from the question to avoid people trying to "solve" that problem; I'm considering the viability of an annular ~f/0.25 Cassegrain telescope built inside a monolithic glass disk. The interest in colored glass is as a way to suppress total internal reflection on the "extra" surfaces by diffusion doping the glass just inside the surface to be absorptive. So: very colored, preferably opaque at the surface with a gradient to clear a few mm inside.
